# Add value temporary below the field

Tags: jquery, ajax

i type value in upper section text fields and when i click add button then i want to show this, which i enter upper section text fields,this values show in below the table in temporary, how can i do this using jquery or anything? my form design code is below
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ih5D.jpg)
index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<title></title>

</head>

<body>
<div>New Invoice</div>

<br />
<p></p>

<form name="" action="" method="post">
<table width="1112" border="0">
<tr><td><font size="-1">Products/Services</font></td>
<td><font size="-1">Description</font></td>
<td><font size="-1">UoM</font></td>
<td><font size="-1">QTY</font></td>
<td><font size="-1">Unit Price</font></td>
<td><font size="-1">Discount (%) </font></td>
<td><font size="-1">Tax</font></td>
<td><font size="-1">Action</font></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<select name="Pro/serv" onChange="my_validate_func()" id="pro_serv">
<option value=""></option>
<option value="" ><font size="-1">Add New Product</font></option>

<option value="Development"><font size="-1">Development</font></option>
<option value="Maintance"><font size="-1">Maintance</font></option>

</select>
</td>
<td><input type="text" name="desc" id="desc" value=""  /></td>
<td><input type="text" name="umo" onchange="validate_func()" /></td>
<td><input type="number" name="qty" style="height:16px; width:34px;" /></td>
<td><input type="text" name="unitprice" id="unitprice"  value="" /></td>
<td><input type="text" name="discount" onchange="validate_func()" /></td>
<td><input type="text" name="tax" id="tax" value=""  /></td>

<td><a href="#"><img src="img/add.jpg" height="40px" width="50px" /></a></td>
</table>
</form>
<table width="1112" border="0" style="background-color:#3399FF">
<tr>
<td><font color="#FFFFFF"><font size="-1">No</font></font></td>
<td><font color="#FFFFFF"><font size="-1">Products/Services</font></font></td>
<td><font color="#FFFFFF"><font size="-1">Description</font></font></td>
<td><font color="#FFFFFF"><font size="-1">UoM</font></font></td>
<td><font color="#FFFFFF"><font size="-1">QTY</font></font></td>
<td><font color="#FFFFFF"><font size="-1">Unit Price</font></font></td>
<td><font color="#FFFFFF"><font size="-1">Value</font></font></td>
<td><font color="#FFFFFF"><font size="-1">Discount</font></font></td>
<td><font color="#FFFFFF"><font size="-1">Tax</font></font></td>
<td><font color="#FFFFFF"><font size="-1">Action</font></font></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><font color="#FFFFFF"><font size="-1"></font></font></td>
<td><font color="#FFFFFF"><font size="-1"></font></font></td>
<td><font color="#FFFFFF"><font size="-1"></font></font></td>
<td><font color="#FFFFFF"><font size="-1"></font></font></td>
<td><font color="#FFFFFF"><font size="-1"></font></font></td>
<td><font color="#FFFFFF"><font size="-1"></font></font></td>
<td><font color="#FFFFFF"><font size="-1"></font></font></td>
<td><font color="#FFFFFF"><font size="-1"></font></font></td>
<td><font color="#FFFFFF"><font size="-1"></font></font></td>
<td><font color="#FFFFFF"><font size="-1"></font></font></td>
</tr>
</table>
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<font size="+1">Total Amount</font>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why *php* tag? Neither the question nor the code is related to PHP.

Comment: Your question is unclear and doesn't include _any_ attempt of solving your issue (which I don't really understand). It doesn't even contain any code, just HTML markup.

Comment: see the image which i attach